# How do I avoid making a shallow copy of a function inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

I'm trying to write a symbol handling calculator in JavaScript. I iterate through a list of symbols. My sample input is 1+2.

```
for <every element in the list> {
    ...
    // this case handles simple numbers
    var tmp = o.val;
    list[pos] = {type: 'expression', val: +tmp, calc: function (x) {return +tmp} };

    ...
    // this case handles addition
    var v1 = list[pos-1].val, v2 = list[pos+1].val;
    var f1 = list[pos-1].calc, f2 = list[pos+1].calc;
    list[pos-1] = {type: 'expression', val: v1 + ' + ' + v2, calc: function (x) {return f1(x) + f2(x)} };
    ...
}
alert(list[0].val + '=' + list[0].calc(0));
```

The problem is that this displays 4 rather than 3. The call to calc() for the first operand doesn't return 1 anymore but 2. I wish 'calc' to hold the current values, to make a deep copy of the f1 and f2 functions. How do I achieve this? What is a good programming practice?

Comment: It's not about shallow vs. deep copy. The issue is that all those functions share a reference to the same variable "tmp".  See the linked duplicate question for more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the correct explanation has already been linked, this is a simple solution to the problem: You'll have to open a new variable scope to make sure that "tmp" is actually a new variable each time, not the same one over and over again:

```
for <every element in the list> {
  (function() {
    ... loop body ...
  )();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
  var temp = i;
  funcs.push(function() { console.log(temp) });
}

funcs[0](); // 1  - expected 0
funcs[1](); // 1
```

The problem is that your functions create a closure over temp. They work on the actual temp variable, not on a copy of the value of the temp variable when they are defined.

The solution is simple: create a copy of the temp variable (by passing it as parameter to a function):

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
  var temp = i;
  funcs.push(function(copy) { // anonymous function that copies temp
      return function() { console.log(copy); }
    }(temp) // call the anonymous function
  );
}

funcs[0](); // 0
funcs[1](); // 1
```